# failed to resolve compile 'com.android.support:cardView-v7:25.3.1'

Tags: android

This is my project code I am getting an error of

> **failed to resolve:  compile 'com.android.support:cardView-v7:25.3.1'**

I have reinstalled Android support Repository (rev 47 ) but it didn't work and still giving me the error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25

        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardView-v7:25.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have capitalised 'v' in cardview.

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardView-v7:25.3.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

On a side note, please use the same version for all dependencies in a single group. For example, use 25.4.0 for all dependencies in group `com.android.support`

Comment: thanx a lot BhalchandraSW